# Latitude & longitude coordinates of Australian states/territories for database using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, search

We have a database which has location-based search using Google Maps API. However searching by state or territory in Australia is problematic because Google Maps locates these at the centre of the states and most population centres in Australia are on the coast.

We need to hand code in the latitudes and longitudes so that when someone searches for the state 'NSW', for example, the database returns relevant results. Does anyone know where to find a list of the coordinates for the boundaries of Australian states & territories to code into the database?

This will save our busy programmer a lot of time. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer named - thought I should talk about what we finally did to implement this feature:

To clarify what this is actually used for, this database is for searching events which may have a geographical location.

At first I found this free map data: https://www.ga.gov.au/products/servlet/controller?event=GEOCAT_DETAILS&catno=60803.

However the data was difficult to work with and we decided to simply generate a basic outline of each of the states using Google Maps's My Maps feature (which RMW did).

I then created a pl/sql implementation of the PNPOLY function, and wrote the search code to run the PNPOLY function comparing the lat and lng of each event with the state outlines (exported from My Maps) and to only return events within the boundaries.

There were 2 main problems with this:

- Towns/Cities on the border betwen 2 states were sometimes seen as being in the wrong state due to the low resolution of the state outlines.
- Concern that the implementation was inefficient/inelegant (though no perf testing was done).

That implementation would probably have worked fine except for the first issue - towns were appearing in the wrong state.

The current implementation abandons the PNPOLY function in favour of a much simpler solution:

1. I added boolean columns to the events table - one for each state/territory in Australia.
2. when events are geocoded, we pull the state name out of the Google Maps API result and then compare it to a list of state names - if one matches we set the flag for that state to TRUE.
3. When searching, the state restriction simply becomes WHERE in_wa = TRUE (for searching events within Western Australia).
4. To migrate the existing events which didn't have the flags set, I didn't want to waste the PNPOLY code, and didn't want to hammer Google Maps with requests, so I wrote a migration to run the PNPOLY check over each event and set the correct flag for each event - this caused some current events to have the wrong state set because of the same issue above, but this won't affect future events.

You can see it in action at http://collectiveaction.com.au/events - choose from the state dropdown and click 'Update search results'.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Australian states boundaries to [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) as an XML file. Just beware that the [data license](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) requires you to share derivative works.

Comment: Thanks Jaime. Hopefully one of these solutions will sort the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my gist: [XML of state polygons](https://gist.github.com/dlin-me/6c583ca29ed6fa253f2f). However, for some states, it comes with  **too** many points and it could become a performance killer if you need to match a point with states for example. If you want to have a simple version, you can try using this [tool](http://www.gmapgis.com/) to generate the polygon coordinates yourself.

Hope this help solving someone's pain.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, can actually have an javascript array with the names of states and the related latlong that you want to centre the map?

So if someone look for NSW, then you load -33.833578,151.190872.

```
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( -33.833578,151.190872);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
```

Let me know if that helps. Otherwise you can contact me as I'm in Adelaide :)

Cheers,

Ives

Comment: Thanks for that I'll ask the developer (who is ex-Adelaide btw).